# read data through spring batch and return data outside the job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I read everywhere how to read data in spring batch itemReader and write in database using itemWriter, but I wanted to just read data using spring batch then somehow I wanted to access this list of items outside the job. I need to perform remaining processing after job finished.
The reason I wanted to do this is because I need to perform a lot of validations on every item. I have to validate each item's variable xyz if it exists in list(which is not available within job). After performing a lot of processing I have to insert information in different tables using JPA. Please help me out!

Comment: Why are you not able to do the validations from within the job?  It seems like the validation logic would make sense to be put in the processor step of your job.

Comment: I need a lot of lists to validate each row data and these lists can not be passed through jobParameters to job that's why it's easy for me to do this processing outside the job

Comment: Why don't you create a `@Service` bean that acts as a validation service.  Then you can `@Autowire` it into your `ItemProcessor`.

Comment: You are right it is also a way but in my case all data is available before initiating spring batch and I have to provide this data which is already fetched.

Comment: I have implemented the solution, I did reading of file by calling doRead function of FlatFileItemWriter then performed rest processing... Can you please tell me one more thing that is I have to process a file.. I want to know what will be the difference in processing if I will set isQuoteCharacter() to false for class DelimitedLineTokenizer in spring batch.